# Is reverberate a dialogue tag?

Tags: grammar, commas, dialogue

Just like the title say and here are the examples: 
“Took you long enough.” Without warning, her voice reverberated from my side.
“Ngh! Phew… Oh no!” A voice reverberated from the crash site and footsteps drew closer to me. 

I think the second one can get away without being a dialogue tag, but... what about the first one?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would have been helpful to consider the meanings and definitions of *reverberate* before posing your question.

Comment: _Reverberated_ is not an equivalent of _said_.

Comment: Neither example includes a dialogue tag. The quotation should be part of the same sentence as the tag.

Comment: perhaps you're thinking of *rebutted*? Here's a list of reporting verbs https://www.tru.ca/__shared/assets/Reporting_Verbs30249.pdf AND [What is a dialogue tag?](https://thewritepractice.com/dialogue-tags/)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Wait! That's pretty useful!

Answer (score 2):

[Reverberate](https://www.lexico.com/definition/reverberate) (Lexico):

> 1 *no object, usually with adverbial* (of a loud noise) be repeated several times as an echo.
>
> > ‘her deep booming laugh reverberated around the room’
>
> 1.1 (of a place) appear to vibrate because of a loud noise.
>
> > ‘the hall reverberated with laughter’
>
> 1.2 *archaic with object* Return or re-echo (a sound)
>
> > ‘oft did the cliffs reverberate the sound’
>
> 2 *no object, usually with adverbial* Have continuing and serious effects.
>
> > ‘the statements by the professor reverberated through the Capitol’

Making your sentences into dialogue tags indicates that *reverberate* is not a substitute for *said*.

> “Took you long enough,” she reverberated.
> “Ngh! Phew… Oh no!” reverberated the voice.